# MongoDB query: List all fields that have Value NaN

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nan

Assume a MongoDB has a collection with an object "sample1", that has the following fields:

```
/* 1 */ {
    "_id" : 123456,
    "name" : "question",
    "day" : "2018-03-21",
    "field1" : 10,
    "field2" : NaN,
    "field3" : NaN,
    "field4" : NaN,
    "field5" : NaN }

/* 2 */ {
    "_id" : 7896321,
    "name" : "question",
    "day" : "2018-03-22",
    "field1" : NaN,
    "field2" : NaN,
    "field3" : NaN,
    "field4" : NaN,
    "field5" : 20 }
```

What I would like is a "list" of fields that displays only those fields that do not have NaN as a value.
The query might look like

```
db.getCollection('sample1').find({"*" : $ne{NaN}})
```

[Note: All answer I found specify the fieldname (s)=Key. Alas, I need a wildcard instead of the names]

The result of the above demo_query looks like

```
Result:
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 123456,
    "name" : "question",
    "day" : "2018-03-21",
    "field1" : 10
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 7896321,
    "name" : "question",
    "day" : "2018-03-22",
    "field5" : 20
}
```

Thereupon a follow up question: 
Is it possible to modify the above query such, that one either gets 
(A) ONE LIST of fields that have the value NaN or
(B) ONE LIST of fields without NaN ?

```
Result (A): List of fields that have at least in one object a given field might have NaN 
    {"field1"
    "field2" 
    "field3"
    "field4" 
    "field5" }

Result (B): List of fields that never (= in no object of a given collection) have the value NaN 
    {"_id"
    "name"
    "day" }
```

My experience in JS in very limited. Possibly this can be done using PyMongo?

Thanks a million for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator available in the aggregation framework to transform the top-level document (via the system variable **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)**) into an array of key-value pairs i.e. the key holding the field name and the value holds the field value. This can be done with the expression

```
{ "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" }
```

which will return, e.g. the first document with _id: 123456

```
[ 
    {
        "k" : "_id",
        "v" : 123456
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "name",
        "v" : "question"
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "day",
        "v" : "2018-03-21"
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "field1",
        "v" : 10
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "field2",
        "v" : NaN
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "field3",
        "v" : NaN
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "field4",
        "v" : NaN
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "field5",
        "v" : NaN
    }
]
```

On getting this array you can then do some filtering with **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** to then get the desired lists.

---

The following aggregate operation

```
db.getCollection('sample1').aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
        "NaNFields": {
            "$map": {
                "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.v", NaN ] }
                    }
                },
                "as": "field",
                "in": "$$field.k"
            }
        },
        "NonNaNFields": {
            "$map": {
                "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$el.v", NaN ] }
                    }
                },
                "as": "field",
                "in": "$$field.k"
            }
        } 
    } }
])
```

yields

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 123456,
    "name" : "question",
    "day" : "2018-03-21",
    "field1" : 10,
    "field2" : NaN,
    "field3" : NaN,
    "field4" : NaN,
    "field5" : NaN,
    "NaNFields" : [ 
        "field2", 
        "field3", 
        "field4", 
        "field5"
    ],
    "NonNaNFields" : [ 
        "_id", 
        "name", 
        "day", 
        "field1"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 7896321,
    "name" : "question",
    "day" : "2018-03-22",
    "field1" : NaN,
    "field2" : NaN,
    "field3" : NaN,
    "field4" : NaN,
    "field5" : 20,
    "NaNFields" : [ 
        "field1", 
        "field2", 
        "field3", 
        "field4"
    ],
    "NonNaNFields" : [ 
        "_id", 
        "name", 
        "day", 
        "field5"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @user2006697 Using PyMongo you can replace `NaN` with Python's `None`.